# How to use go doc in public repo

Tags: go

I've some question regard `godoc` . I have a private git repository and I want to make it public. How does the documentation work? I've used the command `godoc -html my-tool/cmd> doc.html` to generate it locally make fixes etc, but when we go public how the docs will be there , should I do something or this is automatically generated from public function etc?

Should I submit the generated local doc file either? I guess not but not sure...

Comment: If you publish the repo to one of godoc.org's supported services (GitHub for example), then godoc.org will display the doc for you.  See https://godoc.org/-/about#howto

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to do anything. **godoc.org** will automatically fetch your doc the first time it's requested, and frequently updates its cache, in case of changes to your package.

Comment: Thanks, assume I've more than one package and I want to expose all except one or just one except from all, how can I do it ?

Comment: Then you need to put your private packages in a private repo.